# openSUSE (both 42.3 & Tumbleweed) install - failure to create encrypted partitions

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd, encryption, opensuse

From what I've gathered, the installer needs to install some package to create the encrypted partitions. It may be that it fails because it's trying to install to the partition that's going to be encrypted, although I don't know that for sure.

One solution might be to unpack the iso myself, pre install the needed package, repack & burn the iso.

Any advice on how to do that, or whether there's another easier fix available?

The computer is a new dell inspiron 5577, with 512gb ssd, no spinning disk.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it sorted out. I'm pretty sure if you want root directory (/) encrypted too, you have to enable LVM. It seemed quicker & less error prone to just redo the installation & only encrypt /home so that's what I did & it worked. Thanks anyway & hope this helps anybody.